# How to access the rendered page instead of the loaded page like the window.document object?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new to Javascript so apologies if some of the terminology is incorrect.

I've written a piece of javascript that I'm running from the address bar in Chrome.

It simply displays the first 5 links/anchors on the current page however it only recognises `<a>` tags that were in the HTML page that was originally loaded so with most pages (that are javascript generated) it comes back either undefined or with no anchors.

Javascript:

```
var len = document.anchors.length > 5 ? 5 : document.anchors.length;
if (len > 0){
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<len;i++){
        alert(document.anchors[i]);
    }
}
else {
    alert("There are no anchors on this page");
}
```

I infer from this that windows.document is the loaded html not the rendered html. So, is there an equivalent of the document object for the rendered document instead of the loaded one?

Thanks.

Comment: You should always have rendered html in document object.

Comment: Are you trying to execute the above script before or after the page loads

Comment: Definitely running after it has loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're executing the script in the URL bar, then the document is already loaded. Try this code:

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    if (!anchors[i]) break;
    alert("Found anchor with href: " + anchors[i].href);
}

alert("Found at least " + i + " anchors");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kqa4p57z/

Comment: It works great! Is it actually javascript? I guess it doesn't matter if it works....

Comment: Yes, it's plain JavaScript :)

Answer (score 0):

document.anchors only refers to anchor links with the attribute name, could it be that the anchors added after does not have any name attribute? If so add the name attribute.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks... I can't alter the generated page though